# ggpairs: Plotting only the first two rows of a correlation matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, correlation

I'd like to do some correlation analysis with plotting. As my actual data is too large I used the *mtcars* dataframe to setup an example.

Here the code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

mtcars
library(ggcorrplot)
# Computing correlation matrix
corrmatr_mtcars <- round(cor(subset(mtcars[c(3:7,1)])),1)
head(corrmatr_mtcars[,1:6])
corrmatr_mtcars

# Computing correlation matrix with p-values
corrmatr_mtcars.mat <- cor_pmat(mtcars[c(3:7,1)])
head(corrmatr_mtcars.mat[, 1:6])
corrmatr_mtcars.mat


library(GGally)

ggpairs(mtcars[c(3:7,1)],
        title = "Corr Analysis of...",
        lower = list(continuous = wrap("cor",
                                       size = 3)),
        upper = list(
          continuous = wrap("smooth",
                            alpha = 0.3,
                            size = 0.1))
)
```

With this plot result:

[image]

But, I am **interested only in the correlation of the first two variables against all others**. So, for avoiding unneccessary information and saving place I'd rather like

1. my plot to show only the first two correlation rows. All other correlations could be dropped.
   In the end, I imagine something as follows needing only 3 rows.
2. Subsequently the Corr-Value labels should be placed at the scatterplot panels.>br>

[image]

I couldn't find any option to do so.

Would that even generally be possible with `ggpairs` (without complex functions)?
 If yes: how?
 If no: what could be an approach with a comparable result?

Comment: Errors(3): no ggplot package. `object 'correlation_matrix' not found`, `object 'corrp.mat' not found`. You should hack the code for `ggpairs`.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of these bugs. I fixed them now, - except: I just could not comprehend/retrace what you mean with 'no ggplot package'. In my environment everything works fine. Maybe I misunderstood you!?

Comment: I see that you are learning how to spell package names correctly. There is a "ggplot2" package.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

mtcars
library(ggcorrplot)
# Computing correlation matrix
corrmatr_mtcars <- round(cor(subset(mtcars[c(3:7,1)])),1)
head(corrmatr_mtcars[,1:6])
corrmatr_mtcars

# Computing correlation matrix with p-values
corrmatr_mtcars.mat <- cor_pmat(mtcars[c(3:7,1)])
head(corrmatr_mtcars.mat[, 1:6])
corrmatr_mtcars.mat


library(GGally)

gg1 = ggpairs(mtcars[c(3:7,1)],
        title = "Corr Analysis of...",
        lower = list(continuous = wrap("cor",
                                       size = 3)),
        upper = list(
          continuous = wrap("smooth",
                            alpha = 0.3,
                            size = 0.1))
)

gg1$plots = gg1$plots[1:12]
gg1$yAxisLabels = gg1$yAxisLabels[1:2]
gg1
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely done. Now if you made a "empty plot" You could replace the seventh plot with it and then add a 13th and 14th empty-plot and then run the rest of the diagonals across the third row. (I discarded my efforts at hacking since yours is already better than where I got to.)

Comment: Thanks so far, @Marek and IRTFM, but - according to the second part of my question - how then get the correlation values onto the scatterplot-panels?

Comment: In this case, you will probably have to write your own plot generating function.